# Same login on two different Laravel projects on same server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to create two portals on same server and diferent subdomain:

app1.domain.com

app2.domain.com

I want to separate in two different laravel projects, when it is authenticated in one of the portals in the other portal should be authenticated.

How can i do that? Any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to share the session between your 2 applications? So if you authenticate in the first app you will also be authenticated in the second app? If so you could try to edit the cookie to be set on the wildcard `*.domain.com` and get that session from your other app with a shared db and app key

Comment: yes exactly! @milo526 the database is the same.. I've already tried that 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'), but it doesnt work, What else should I change in the file session.php ?? where is the app key?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

For Laravel in my quick search found some [Packages](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=SSO)

[**jasny/sso**](https://packagist.org/packages/jasny/sso) is one of them, explained as :

How it works
When using SSO, when can distinguish 3 parties:

1. Client - This is the browser of the visitor
2. Broker - The website which is visited
3. Server - The place that holds the user info and credentials

The broker has an id and a secret. These are know to both the broker and server.

When the client visits the broker, it creates a random token, which is stored in a cookie. The broker will then send the client to the server, passing along the broker's id and token. The server creates a hash using the broker id, broker secret and the token. This hash is used to create a link to the users session. When the link is created the server redirects the client back to the broker.

The broker can create the same link hash using the token (from the cookie), the broker id and the broker secret. When doing requests, it passes that has as session id.

The server will notice that the session id is a link and use the linked session. As such, the broker and client are using the same session. When another broker joins in, it will also use the same session.

HTH!

Comment: thanks for your help.. do yo know how to implement jasny/sso with Laravel 5.4

Comment: Do you face any difficulty with installing that package? As I can see a installation and usage guide is given on the link I posted. I haven't installed the package myself but there are 9426 installations of it so it should work for you as well.